# Can someone please explain the Stream package for Angular? What does it do and can I safely remove it?

Tags: angular, package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream

I work on an app where previous developers installed a lot of packages that were never used. I'm going through them, evaluating what I can safely delete without collapsing the whole app. Fun!

I'm currently on Angular 13; I'm about to update it to 16. Cleaning up and updating the packages is a precursor step, because a lot of them are VERY outdated and will get cranky with the Angular update.

One of the packages is Stream, version 0.0.2. The package was last updated 9 years ago. I can't find anywhere in the written code (i.e. not part of the Angular architecture) where it's in use.

When I uninstall it, I get this message. I don't really understand what it means. The app still compiles and seems to work. **Could someone please explain in simple, dummy-friendly terms?** Do I need to delete something else? Do I need to reinstall it and leave it alone because it's a pillar holding up other things? sax\lib doesn't seem to be a package or library in package.json.

> ./node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:163:13-37 - Warning: Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:...\node_modules\sax\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

Thank you very much.